# node-jquery installation errors on Azure server

Tags: jquery, node.js, azure

I know many people are facing the same problem when they install node-jquery (node.js) module on Azure server:

The developer of this module stated that:
"**Many people are having problems getting this module to work on windows.** 
The failure has to do with building contextify on window. It seems to be a windows environment issue. I don't have access to a windows machine so I cannot explore working through the windows install process. If you figure out how to build contextify on windows please send me working instructions!"
[enter link description here](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery#does-not-work-on-windows)

Do someone find a solution to this problem?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: This will be the same for any package that's a [native addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). You'll have to have [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) and [its external dependencies](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) installed to be able to compile and install them. See the "*Native Modules*" section in [Azure's Documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/working-with-node-modules/) for more information. But, in short, you should be able to compile them on your own machine and include them in the deploy.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan :) I didn't what you said and plus I installed 32bit of Node.js and things are working properly.